# Is it possible to insert/erase an element from std::list in O(1) if I store the iterators somewhere. Iterators are kind of pointers.right?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl

say

```
    list<int> l={1,2,3,4,5};
    typedef list<int> lst ;
    lst l={1,2,3,4,5};
    lst::iterator i=l.begin();
    advance(i,2);//let the time complexity be n
    l.erase(i);//what is the time complexity here?
    for(auto i:l)
        cout<<i<<endl;
```

Since list is implemented as doubly linked list, can it not find its previous and next pointer join both and remove the middle one in o(1) time?

Comment: `std::list::erase(iterator pos)`'s complexity is constant time according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase), so `l.erase(i);` should be O(1) I think.

Comment: If you're asking whether the time complexity for the overrides of [`std::list::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) and [`std::list::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) taking a single iterator as parameter are both constant time, i.e. O(1), then the answer is yes. Not sure how [tag:c++11] tag or storing iterators is relevant though?

Comment: I would like to swap two positions without swapping the values but the actual pointers using std::list if I have the iterators.Is that possible with iter_swap using o(1)?

Comment: @PrinzKm again, check [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap). `iter_swap`'s complexity is, again, constant time.

Comment: `iter_swap` will swap the values "pointed to" by the iterators. It will not reorder the nodes in the list.

Comment: You can reorder nodes in a `std::list` without touching the stored objects by the [`splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) member function. It won't look obvious, so I'd create a function to do this sort of optimized swap.